# Unity - jerky motion when going down the slope

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make simple 3rd person character controller using unitys character controller component instead of rigidbody. I have problem when making my character sliding down the slope, the motion is jerky, just as if the character was going down stairs.

I move my character using normal to the ground by reversing its y axis, then i apply some additional gravity and put this vector to charactercontroller.move() function.

Here is some of the code where i apply slide and gravity:

```
void ProcessMotion(){
    MoveVector = transform.TransformDirection (MoveVector);

    if (MoveVector.magnitude > 1)
        MoveVector = Vector3.Normalize (MoveVector);

    ApplySlide ();

    MoveVector *= MoveSpeed;

    MoveVector = new Vector3 (MoveVector.x, VerticalVel, MoveVector.z);

    ApplyGravity ();



    TP_Controller.CharacterController.Move (MoveVector*Time.deltaTime);

}

public void Jump(){
    if (TP_Controller.CharacterController.isGrounded) {
        VerticalVel=jumpSpeed;
    }
}

void SnapAlignCharacterWithCamera(){
    if (MoveVector.x != 0 || MoveVector.z != 0) {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}

void ApplyGravity(){

    if (MoveVector.y > -TermVel) {

        MoveVector = new Vector3 (MoveVector.x, MoveVector.y - Gravity * Time.deltaTime, MoveVector.z);

    } 
    if (TP_Controller.CharacterController.isGrounded && MoveVector.y < - 1) {

        MoveVector = new Vector3 (MoveVector.x, -1, MoveVector.z);

    }

}

void ApplySlide(){
    if (!TP_Controller.CharacterController.isGrounded) {

        return;
    }
    SlideDirection = Vector3.zero;

    RaycastHit hitInfo;


    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position , Vector3.down, out hitInfo)) {

        if(hitInfo.normal.y < SlideTreshold){
            SlideDirection = new Vector3(hitInfo.normal.x, -hitInfo.normal.y, hitInfo.normal.z)*10;
        }

    }
    if (SlideDirection.magnitude < MaxMagnitude) {
        MoveVector += SlideDirection;

        //Debug.DrawLine (transform.position,transform.position + new Vector3(hitInfo.normal.x*0.5f,-hitInfo.normal.y,hitInfo.normal.z*0.5f), Color.red,1.0f);
    }else {

        MoveVector = SlideDirection;
    }

}
```

And here are screens with gizmos that show path of the object:
[Sliding slowly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDgek.jpg)
[Sliding 10xfaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRQaa.jpg)

In advance thanks for your help!

Comment: where you able to find a solution for this? im facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the scale of your objects, but it looks like your raycast is coming from inside of your capsule, and possibly colliding with the bottom. The resulting `RaycastHit` would report that information, which is a normal that points downward, so when you reverse it, you are heading upwards, creating the sawtooth effect.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked it by displaying normal and it changes on different slopes so its not the case.